# Have git show in command line changes that occured for a single file in a large commit without changing HEAD

Tags: git

Let's say I have a few commits in a large repository with many branches.

```
projectname:some/branch* λ git log --oneline -n4 --graph
*   742b5fd1a (HEAD -> some/branch) Added many bugs
| * 16963a72a (TAG: Release_9, upstream/version_B) Release Test fix
| * 5643f6a7c (tag: RELEASE_8) Fixed bug
| * e31f00146 (tag: RELEASE_7) Fixed race condition
```

I want to see the changes that occurred to `core/library_foo/foo.cpp` for RELEASE_8 (`5643f6a7c`), without checking out RELEASE_8. I can't checkout because the size of the repository is very large, so checking out takes an extremely long time (*many minutes*). This commit also has a few hundred files changed, hence wanting to limit it to a single file.

I am expecting to do the following, but neither of which work (they just show the git commit message without a textual diff of the file, or give me errors). This file DID change for that commit, based on viewing the commit in sublime merge, and gitk.

```
git show 5643f6a7c core/library_foo/foo.cpp
git show 5643f6a7c:core/library_foo/foo.cpp
git show 5643f6a7c -- core/library_foo/foo.cpp

git log 5643f6a7c core/library_foo/foo.cpp  
git log 5643f6a7c:core/library_foo/foo.cpp
git log 5643f6a7c -- core/library_foo/foo.cpp
```

I had to adjust the file paths, commit hashes, commit messages, tag names, and branch names, due to this example being done on a private repository. This is for a pretty recent git (2.29.0).

Comment: What's the output of `git show --name-status 5643f6a7c`? Is the file listed there?

Comment: When you say that the file "changed in the commit", you mean "with respect to its parent commit"? If so, `git show <hash> -- <path>` should show it. This assumes `5643f6a7c` is not itself a merge commit (but if your `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` output is cut and pasted, it's not a merge commit; if it were a merge we'd see more ```|\``` things coming out to show the merge-ness). Hm, unless perhaps `-n4` cuts them off...?

Comment: To put it another way: is `5643f6a7c` an ordinary single-parent commit, or is it a merge commit? If it is a merge, `git show` won't be able to show a proper diff against its (single) parent, because it does not have a single parent.

Comment: @torek Oh wow, you answered it for me, yes that is a merge commit. While I was trying to remove confidential information from the commits, I had to adjust the git log a bit, making it not look like a merge commit anymore. I tested git show <hash> -- <path> on another repo, and it works as expected for non merge commits, but on merge commits it shows what I see. If you want to make your comment an answer, I will mark it as the answer. Now I will just have to figure out how to re-ask my question for merges commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431408/have-git-show-in-command-line-changes-that-occured-for-a-single-file-in-a-large?noredirect=1#comment115680528_65431408) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431408/have-git-show-in-command-line-changes-that-occured-for-a-single-file-in-a-large?noredirect=1#comment115704515_65431408), it turns out commit `5643f6a7c` is in fact a merge commit.  The `git show` command has special handling for merge commits and winds up showing no diff for this file.

The reason `git show` winds up showing nothing is a little bit complicated in full detail, but has to do with the following:

- Each commit contains a *full snapshot:* a copy of *every file* as of the form it had at the time you (or whoever) made that commit.
- Each commit also contains information about the commit itself.  We call this the commit's *metadata*, to distinguish it from the main data (the snapshot).  This includes the name and email address of the person who made commit, for instance.  It also includes the raw hash ID of the commit's *parent commits*.

It's the parent linkage, from a commit to its predecessor commit or commits, that allows Git to show you a diff.  Most commits have just the one parent.  Given that commit `C` follows earlier commit `B`, and both commits have snapshots, Git can simply extract—to a temporary area (in memory or whatever)—*both snapshots* and then compare them.  For each file that is the same, Git says nothing.  For each file that is *different*, Git prints the name of the file and a recipe.  Apply the change-recipe and this will transform the copy of the file as it appears in commit `B` to make it match the copy of the file as it appears in commit `C`.

This recipe, for changing parent commit `B` into child commit `C`, is one form of a *diff*.  This diff is what `git show` shows, after printing a selected (and formatted) part of the metadata from commit `C`.  The `git show` command can do this *because* there is only one earlier commit: commit `B` precedes commit `C` so whatever changed between `B` and `C` is what is of interest.  Adding one or more path-names to a `git show` command limits the diff to just what changed in the selected file(s).

#### Merge commits are slightly different

This whole idea fails when applied to a *merge commit*.  A merge commit is a commit with two or more parent commits.  Other than having the two or more parents, a merge commit is like any other commit: it has a snapshot and metadata.

In general, we get merge commits by running `git merge`.  (There are other ways to make merge commits and `git merge` does not always make merge commits, so there's no guaranteed one-to-one correspondence here, but that's the usual way to make a merge.  Note, by the way, that the noun form, *a merge*, refers to a merge commit, probably made by `git merge`; the verb form, *to merge*, is the process that `git merge` uses to come up with the content for the snapshot.

The merge process actually involves at least *three* commits.  We can see how a typical merge comes about by drawing the setup we get if we have two divergent branches:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Here, the two *branch names*, `br1` and `br2`, select commits `J` and `L` respectively.  As with all commits, commits `J` and `L` have snapshots and parents:

- The (single) parent of commit `J` is commit `I`.  Commit `I`, of course, also has a snapshot and a parent; its parent is commit `H`.
- The (single) parent of commit `L` is commit `K`, whose parent is commit `H`.

So both branches descend from a bunch of *shared* commits, ending at commit `H`.  Commits `H` and `G` and anything earlier are on both branches, but since commit `H` is the *last* such commit, it's also the best commit for doing the merging work—the *to merge* part of a merge operation.

In order to merge any work we did in branch `br1` with any work anyone did in branch `br2`, we `git checkout br1` to select commit `J` as our current commit:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and then run `git merge br2` to tell Git to locate commit `L` and start the merging process.  Git knows we are on `J`, finds `L`, and uses the *connections* from each commit to find the *best shared* commit, `H`, to use as what Git calls the *merge base*.

Since each commit holds a snapshot, `H` holds a snapshot.  By comparing the snapshot in `H` to that in `J`, Git can figure out what *we* changed in `br1`.  Likewise, by comparing the snapshot in `H` to that in `L`, Git can figure out what *they* changed in `br2`.  Git can then *combine the changes*, which is the heart of the to-merge, merge-as-a-verb process.  By applying the *combined* changes to the snapshot taken from commit `H`, Git *keeps our work* but also *adds their work*.

If all goes well with this combining process, Git can make a new *merge commit* `M` on its own.  If not, Git stops and gets us to provide the correct final snapshot.  We fix any conflicts, use `git add` if needed, and run `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to indicate that we fixed the merge conflicts and have provided the correct final snapshot.  Either way, Git makes this new commit `M`—but instead of linking back to *just* `J` or *just* `L`, the new snapshot links back to *both* `J` *and* `L`, like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

#### Showing a merge commit

Given that `git show` needs to diff commits, which ones should it diff?  If we start with merge commit `M`, we could compare its snapshot to that in `J`, or to that in `L`.  The results will be different, depending on which parent we pick.

Git's default answer is not to pick just one.  Instead, Git can:

- compare `J` vs `M`, *and*
- compare `L` vs `M`

and then *combine* these two diffs in a rather peculiar way.  There are two different ways to combine the diffs.  One is called a *combined diff* and the other is called a *dense combined diff*.  They're very similar, and both of them have an odd feature: they *completely discard* any file that *exactly matches* any of the parents.  **So, for instance, if `core/library_foo/foo.cpp` in `M` matches *either* `core/library_foo/foo.cpp` in `J` *or* `core/library_foo/foo.cpp` in `L`, `git show` won't show it at all.**

(I suspect the goal behind combined diffs was to show how merge conflicts were resolved.  Unfortunately, the algorithm used to show the combined diffs entirely fails to do that when the merge conflict was resolved by taking the `--ours` or `--theirs` file, *even if that was an error*.  But that's just speculation; what we actually have is the code.  The behavior is as described: show a diff only when the merge result differs from *all parents*.)

#### How to work around this

There are several easy ways to work around this problem:

- You can use `git diff` directly.

  Suppose, for instance, you want to compare commit `5643f6a7c` to its *first parent*.  Then `git diff 5643f6a7c^ 5643f6a7c` will do the job.  In fact, by using `git diff` directly, you can choose exactly which parent to use.
- You can use `git show -m`.

  The `-m` flag directs `git show` to "virtually split" the merge.  Suppose merge `M` has parents `J` and `L`, as in our example above.  Then `git show -m hash-of-M` will display *two* diffs.  The first will compare `J`, the first parent, to `M`.  The second will compare `L`, the second parent, to `M`.
- You can use `git show --first-parent -m`.

  As before, the `-m` option splits the merge, but this time, the `--first-parent` option suppresses all diffs *except* the first-parent diff.

The first-parent notion makes use of the fact that, in all cases, a merge commit resulting from `git merge` writes out the parents in order:

- The first parent of the new merge commit is the commit that *was* the *current commit* at the time we ran `git merge`.  For our example, that was commit `J`, because we ran `git checkout br1` before we ran `git merge`.
- The remaining parents are those we named on the command line, in the order we named them.

There are no *flags* to pick out any particular parent, but we can use that hat-suffix notation, as in `5643f6a7c^`, to do so: `5643f6a7c^2` means the second parent, `5643f6a7c^3` means the third, and so on.  The number after the hat is the choice of parent.  Most merge commits only have two parents anyway, though, so `^1` and `^2` are the most sensible suffixes.  If you leave off the number—as in `5643f6a7c^`—this means *first parent*.

Note that the `~` suffix, as in `5643f6a7c~4`, means *repeat `^1` that many times*.  So when using `5643f6a7c~4` we go back to the commit's first parent, then to *that* commit's first parent, and so on.  (This relies on the fact that commits almost always have at least one parent.)  There's no particular reason to use the `~` suffix for this particular case, but if it's easier to type, you can use `5643f6a7c~` or `5643f6a7c~1` in place of `5643f6a7c^`.

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely above and beyond, thank you so much!